# python concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor: Performance of .submit() vs .map()

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I am using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to find the occurrence of a number from a number range. The intent is to investigate the amount of speed-up performance gained from concurrency. To benchmark performance, I have a control - a serial code to perform said task (shown below). I have written 2 concurrent codes, one using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()` and the other using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` to perform the same task. They are shown below. Advice on drafting the former and latter can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42049066/5722359) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42056738/5722359), respectively.

The task issued to all three codes was to find the number of occurrences of the number 5 in the number range of 0 to 1E8. Both `.submit()` and `.map()` were assigned 6 workers, and `.map()` had a chunksize of 10,000. The manner to discretise the workload were identical in the concurrent codes. However, the function used to find occurrences in both codes were different. This was because the way arguments were passed to a function called by `.submit()` and `.map()` were different.

All 3 codes reported the same number of occurrences, i.e. 56,953,279 times. However, the time taken to complete the task were very different. `.submit()` performed 2 times faster than the control while `.map()` took twice as long as the control to complete it's task.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to know if the slow performance of `.map()` is an artifact of my coding or it is inherently slow?" If the former, how can I improve it. I am just surprise that it performed slower than the control as there will be no much incentive to use it.
2. I like to know if there is anyway to make `.submit()` code perform even faster. A condition I have is that the function `_concurrent_submit()` must return an iterable with the numbers/occurrences containing the number 5.

**Benchmark Results**
[image: benchmark results]

**concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import concurrent.futures as cf
from time import time
from traceback import print_exc

def _findmatch(nmin, nmax, number):
    '''Function to find the occurrence of number in range nmin to nmax and return
       the found occurrences in a list.'''
    print('\n def _findmatch', nmin, nmax, number)
    start = time()
    match=[]
    for n in range(nmin, nmax):
        if number in str(n):
            match.append(n)
    end = time() - start
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(match),end))
    return match

def _concurrent_submit(nmax, number, workers):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.submit to
       find the occurences of a given number in a number range in a parallelised
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunk = nmax // workers
    futures = []
    found =[]
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        for i in range(workers):
            cstart = chunk * i
            cstop = chunk * (i + 1) if i != workers - 1 else nmax
            futures.append(executor.submit(_findmatch, cstart, cstop, number))
        # 2.2. Instruct workers to process results as they come, when all are
        #      completed or .....
        cf.as_completed(futures) # faster than cf.wait()
        # 2.3. Consolidate result as a list and return this list.
        for future in futures:
            for f in future.result():
                try:
                    found.append(f)
                except:
                    print_exc()
        foundsize = len(found)
        end = time() - start
        print('within statement of def _concurrent_submit():')
        print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(foundsize, end))
    return found

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.
    workers = 6     # Pool of workers

    start = time()
    a = _concurrent_submit(nmax, number, workers)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print('workers = ', workers)
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(a),end))
```

**concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map()**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import concurrent.futures as cf
import itertools
from time import time
from traceback import print_exc

def _findmatch(listnumber, number):    
    '''Function to find the occurrence of number in another number and return
       a string value.'''
    #print('def _findmatch(listnumber, number):')
    #print('listnumber = {0} and ref = {1}'.format(listnumber, number))
    if number in str(listnumber):
        x = listnumber
        #print('x = {0}'.format(x))
        return x 

def _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a parallelised
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunk = nmax // workers
    futures = []
    found =[]
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        for i in range(workers):
            cstart = chunk * i
            cstop = chunk * (i + 1) if i != workers - 1 else nmax
            numberlist = range(cstart, cstop)
            futures.append(executor.map(_findmatch, numberlist,
                                        itertools.repeat(number),
                                        chunksize=10000))
        # 2.3. Consolidate result as a list and return this list.
        for future in futures:
            for f in future:
                if f:
                    try:
                        found.append(f)
                    except:
                        print_exc()
        foundsize = len(found)
        end = time() - start
        print('within statement of def _concurrent(nmax, number):')
        print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(foundsize, end))
    return found

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.
    workers = 6     # Pool of workers

    start = time()
    a = _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print('workers = ', workers)
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(a),end))
```

**Serial Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from time import time

def _serial(nmax, number):    
    start = time()
    match=[]
    nlist = range(nmax)
    for n in nlist:
        if number in str(n):match.append(n)
    end=time()-start
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(match),end))
    return match

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.

    start = time()
    a = _serial(nmax, number)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(a),end))
```

**Update 13th Feb 2017:**

In addition to @niemmi answer, I have provide an answer following some personal research to show:

1. how to further speed-up @niemmi's `.map()` and `.submit()` solutions, and
2. when `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` can led to more speed-up than `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Overview:**

There are 2 parts to my answer:

- Part 1 shows how to gain more speed-up from @niemmi's `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` solution.
- Part 2 shows when the `ProcessPoolExecutor`'s subclasses `.submit()` and `.map()` yield non-equivalent compute times.

**=======================================================================**

**Part 1: More Speed-up for ProcessPoolExecutor.map()**

**Background:**
This section builds on @niemmi's `.map()` solution, which by itself is excellent. While doing some research on his discretization scheme to better understand how that interact with .map() chunksizes arguement, I found this interesting solution.

I regard @niemmi's definition of `chunk = nmax // workers` to be a definition for chunksize, i.e. a smaller size of actual number range (given task) to be tackled by each worker in the worker pool. Now, this definition is premised on the assumption that if a computer has x number of workers, dividing the task equally among each worker will result in optimum use of each worker and hence the total task will be completed fastest. Therefore, the number of chunks to break up a given task into should always equal the number of pool workers. However, is this assumption correct?

**Proposition:** Here, I propose that the above assumption does not always lead to the fastest compute time when used with `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()`. Rather, **discretising a task to an amount greater than the number of pool workers can lead to speed-up, i.e. faster completion of a given task**.

**Experiment:** I have modified @niemmi's code to allow the number of discretized tasks to exceed the number of pool workers. This code is given below and used to fin the number of times the number 5 appears in the number range of 0 to 1E8. I have executed this code using 1, 2, 4, and 6 pool workers and for various ratio of number of discretized tasks vs the number of pool workers. For each scenario, 3 runs were made and the compute times were tabulated. "*Speed-up*" is defined here as the average compute time using equal number of chunks and pool workers over the average compute time of when the number of discretized tasks is greater than the number of pool workers.

**Findings:**

[image: nchunk over nworkers]

1. Figure on left shows the compute time taken by all the scenarios mentioned in the experiment section. It shows that the **compute time taken by *number of chunks / number of workers = 1*  is always greater than the compute time taken by *number of chunks > number of workers*.** That is, the former case is always less efficient than the latter.
2. Figure on right shows that **a speed-up of 1.2 times or more was gained when the *number of chunks / number of workers* reach a threshold value of 14 or more**. It is interesting to observe that the speed-up trend also occurred when `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` was executed with 1 worker.

**Conclusion:** When customizing the number of discrete tasks that ProcessPoolExecutor.map()` should use to solve a given task, it is prudent to ensure that this number is greater than the number pool workers as this practice shortens compute time.

**concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map() code. (revised parts only)**

```
def _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a parallelised
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunksize = nmax // num_of_chunks
    futures = []
    found =[]
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        cstart = (chunksize * i for i in range(num_of_chunks))
        cstop = (chunksize * i if i != num_of_chunks else nmax
                 for i in range(1, num_of_chunks + 1))
        futures = executor.map(_findmatch, cstart, cstop,
                               itertools.repeat(number))
        # 2.2. Consolidate result as a list and return this list.
        for future in futures:
            #print('type(future)=',type(future))
            for f in future:
                if f:
                    try:
                        found.append(f)
                    except:
                        print_exc()
        foundsize = len(found)
        end = time() - start
        print('\n within statement of def _concurrent(nmax, number):')
        print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(foundsize, end))
    return found

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.
    workers = 4     # Pool of workers
    chunks_vs_workers = 14 # A factor of =>14 can provide optimum performance  
    num_of_chunks = chunks_vs_workers * workers

    start = time()
    a = _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print('nmax={}, workers={}, num_of_chunks={}'.format(
          nmax, workers, num_of_chunks))
    print('workers = ', workers)
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(a),end))
```

**=======================================================================**

**Part 2: Total compute time from using ProcessPoolExecutor subclasses .submit() and .map() can be dissimilar when returning a sorted/ordered result list.**

**Background:** I have amended both the `.submit()` and `.map()` codes to allow an "apple-to-apple" comparison of their compute time and the ability to visualize the compute time of the main code, the compute time of the _concurrent method called by the main code to performs the concurrent operations, and the compute time for each discretized task/worker called by the _concurrent method. Furthermore, the concurrent method in these codes was structured to return an unordered and ordered list of the result directly from the future object of  `.submit()` and the iterator of `.map()`. Source code is provided below (*Hope it helps you.*).

**Experiments** These two newly improved codes were used to perform the same experiment described in Part 1, save that only 6 pool workers were considered and the python built-in `list` and `sorted` methods were used to return an unordered and ordered list of the results to the main section of the code, respectively.

**Findings:**
 [image: .submit vs .map plus list vs sorted]

1. From the _concurrent method's result, we can see the compute times of the _concurrent method used to create all the Future objects of `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()`, and to create the iterator of `ProcessPoolExecutor.map()`, as a function of the number of discretized task over the number of pool workers, are equivalent. This result simply means that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` sub-classes `.submit()` and `.map()` are equally efficient/fast.
2. Comparing the compute times from main and it's _concurrent method, we can see that main ran longer than it's _concurrent method. This is to be expected as their time difference reflects the amount of compute times of  the `list` and `sorted` methods (and that of the other methods encased within these methods). Clearly seen, the `list` method took less compute time to return a result list than the `sorted` method. The average compute times of the `list` method for both the .submit() and .map() codes were similar, at ~0.47sec. The average compute time of the sorted method for the .submit() and .map() codes was 1.23sec and 1.01sec, respectively. In other words, the `list` method performed 2.62 times and 2.15 times faster than `sorted` method for the .submit() and .map() codes, respectively.
3. It is not clear why the `sorted` method generated an ordered list from
   `.map()` faster than from `.submit()`, as the number of discretized
   tasks increased more than the number of pool workers, save when the
   number of discretized tasks equaled the number of pool workers.
   That said, these findings shows that the decision to use the equally fast `.submit()` or `.map()` sub-classes can be encumbered by the sorted method. For example, if the intent is to generate an ordered list in the shortest time possible, the use of ProcessPoolExecutor.map() should be preferred over `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit()` as `.map()` can allow the shortest total compute time.
4. The discretization scheme mentioned in Part 1 of my answer is shown here to speed-up the performance of both the `.submit()` and `.map()` sub-classes. The amount of speed-up can be as much as 20% over the case when the number of discretized tasks equaled the number of pool workers.

**Improved .map() code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import concurrent.futures as cf
from time import time
from itertools import repeat, chain 


def _findmatch(nmin, nmax, number):
    '''Function to find the occurence of number in range nmin to nmax and return
       the found occurences in a list.'''
    start = time()
    match=[]
    for n in range(nmin, nmax):
        if number in str(n):
            match.append(n)
    end = time() - start
    #print("\n def _findmatch {0:<10} {1:<10} {2:<3} found {3:8} in {4:.4f}sec".
    #      format(nmin, nmax, number, len(match),end))
    return match

def _concurrent(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a concurrent
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunksize = nmax // num_of_chunks
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        cstart = (chunksize * i for i in range(num_of_chunks))
        cstop = (chunksize * i if i != num_of_chunks else nmax
                 for i in range(1, num_of_chunks + 1))
        futures = executor.map(_findmatch, cstart, cstop, repeat(number))
    end = time() - start
    print('\n within statement of def _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks):')
    print("found in {0:.4f}sec".format(end))
    return list(chain.from_iterable(futures)) #Return an unordered result list
    #return sorted(chain.from_iterable(futures)) #Return an ordered result list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.
    workers = 6     # Pool of workers
    chunks_vs_workers = 30 # A factor of =>14 can provide optimum performance 
    num_of_chunks = chunks_vs_workers * workers

    start = time()
    found = _concurrent(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print('nmax={}, workers={}, num_of_chunks={}'.format(
          nmax, workers, num_of_chunks))
    #print('found = ', found)
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(found),end))
```

**Improved .submit() code.** 
 
This code is same as .map code except you replace the _concurrent method with the following:

```
def _concurrent(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.submit to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a concurrent
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunksize = nmax // num_of_chunks
    futures = []
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        for i in range(num_of_chunks):
            cstart = chunksize * i
            cstop = chunksize * (i + 1) if i != num_of_chunks - 1 else nmax
            futures.append(executor.submit(_findmatch, cstart, cstop, number))
    end = time() - start
    print('\n within statement of def _concurrent_submit(nmax, number, workers, num_of_chunks):')
    print("found in {0:.4f}sec".format(end))
    return list(chain.from_iterable(f.result() for f in cf.as_completed(
        futures))) #Return an unordered list
    #return list(chain.from_iterable(f.result() for f in cf.as_completed(
    #    futures))) #Return an ordered list
```

**=======================================================================**

Answer (score 14):

You're comparing apples to oranges here. When using `map` you produce all the `1E8` numbers and transfer them to worker processes. This takes a lot of time compared to actual execution. When using `submit` you just create 6 sets of parameters that get transferred.

If you change `map` to operate with the same principle you'll get numbers that are close to each other:

```
def _findmatch(nmin, nmax, number):
    '''Function to find the occurrence of number in range nmin to nmax and return
       the found occurrences in a list.'''
    print('\n def _findmatch', nmin, nmax, number)
    start = time()
    match=[]
    for n in range(nmin, nmax):
        if number in str(n):
            match.append(n)
    end = time() - start
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(match),end))
    return match

def _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a parallelised
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    start = time()
    chunk = nmax // workers
    futures = []
    found =[]
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        cstart = (chunk * i for i in range(workers))
        cstop = (chunk * i if i != workers else nmax for i in range(1, workers + 1))
        futures = executor.map(_findmatch, cstart, cstop, itertools.repeat(number))

        # 2.3. Consolidate result as a list and return this list.
        for future in futures:
            for f in future:
                try:
                    found.append(f)
                except:
                    print_exc()
        foundsize = len(found)
        end = time() - start
        print('within statement of def _concurrent(nmax, number):')
        print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(foundsize, end))
    return found
```

You could improve the performance of submit by using [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) correctly. For given iterable of futures it will return an iterator that will `yield` futures in the order they complete.

You could also skip the copying of the data to another array and use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to combine the results from futures to single iterable:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf
import itertools
from time import time
from traceback import print_exc
from itertools import chain

def _findmatch(nmin, nmax, number):
    '''Function to find the occurrence of number in range nmin to nmax and return
       the found occurrences in a list.'''
    print('\n def _findmatch', nmin, nmax, number)
    start = time()
    match=[]
    for n in range(nmin, nmax):
        if number in str(n):
            match.append(n)
    end = time() - start
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(len(match),end))
    return match

def _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers):
    '''Function that utilises concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map to
       find the occurrences of a given number in a number range in a parallelised
       manner.'''
    # 1. Local variables
    chunk = nmax // workers
    futures = []
    found =[]
    #2. Parallelization
    with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        # 2.1. Discretise workload and submit to worker pool
        for i in range(workers):
            cstart = chunk * i
            cstop = chunk * (i + 1) if i != workers - 1 else nmax
            futures.append(executor.submit(_findmatch, cstart, cstop, number))

    return chain.from_iterable(f.result() for f in cf.as_completed(futures))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nmax = int(1E8) # Number range maximum.
    number = str(5) # Number to be found in number range.
    workers = 6     # Pool of workers

    start = time()
    a = _concurrent_map(nmax, number, workers)
    end = time() - start
    print('\n main')
    print('workers = ', workers)
    print("found {0} in {1:.4f}sec".format(sum(1 for x in a),end))
```

Comment: I just studied your `.map()` solution. Wow.. the way you rewrote `cstart` & `cstop` to apply it to `_findmatch()` and `.map()` is ingenious. I did not thought I could do it this way. 1st time using `.map()`. That is why _findmatch in `.map()` code was written different to that in `.submit()` code and the control code, and this resulted in the apple to orange comparison. ;) I tried to include chunksize in `.map()`, but discovered that it caused slower performances. The bigger the `chunksize`, the slower the `.map` code performed. Can you help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: @SunBear If you used my version of map there should be simple explanation. Let's say you have 2 cores on your machine which means that if you properly parallelize the work it can be done in half the time. Now the map implementation splits the work in 6 parts. Let's say you define `chunksize=5` one of the workers gets 5 of the 6 parts resulting 5/6 of the work being processed on one of the cores. In general using a bigger chunksize makes sense but only if it allows work to be split evenly among the workers. Try lowering chunksize with your original `submit`, you should see it slowing down.

Comment: I followed your reasoning till '5/6 of the work being processed on one of the cores. '  What happens when chunksize= 10?  Does this means all the 6 goes into 1 worker and the other workers are idle? What does extra chunksize mean? Pardon me, I am a bit slow here. Incidentally, I found something interesting while figuring out how your chunksize and .map() chunksize together affects the computation speed. See my add-on answer to yours. I think the interaction is causing number of chunks / number of worker << 1 thereby going to the left side of the graphs, i.e longer compute time.

Comment: I have compared the .submit() codes. Using 6 workers and out of 5 runs, the average compute time from your code is ~1.4 time faster than the average compute time from the .submit() code posted in my question. Average time from your code is 6.41sec. Wow..that is awesome!  Comparing the .submit() code and .map() .code with my suggested change, the .submit() code is still faster.

Comment: @SunBear Note that in my solution the numbers yielded from iterable are not ordered. The time savings result from not copying the numbers to a list in main process and not needing to wait chunk containing numbers 5xxxxxxx to complete before consuming the results from following ones. I'll try to expand my answer based on the comments and your answer later.